# Photon irradiance and solid angles

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, intensity

A blackbody is in equilibrium with a radiation field at $\nu$ when
$$
I(\nu)=\frac{8 \pi \nu^{2} }{ c^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{e^{h \nu / k T}-1}\right)
$$
where $T$ is the temperature of the blackbody and $I$ is the intensity in units of photons **per $4 \pi$ solid angle**, per unit bandwidth, per unit area, per unit time. (a lift from this [paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1840606) - which cites Planck for the derivation).

But, the photon irradiance I know, has units of photons per unit area, per unit time, per unit bandwidth, i.e.

$$I(\nu)=\frac{2 \pi \nu^{2}}{c^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{e^{h \nu / k T}-1}\right)$$

Which is widely derived [online](https://www.oceanopticsbook.info/view/light-and-radiometry/level-2/blackbody-radiation). I don't understand the difference in the factor of $4$, or really what **per $4 \pi$ solid angle** means.

Comment: [In response to deleted comment] Mhmm, my question is understanding the origin of the factor of 4. I suspect it is tied up with my misunderstanding of the solid angle. I guess I find it strange quoting 4$\pi$ solid angle - isn't that the entirety of the sphere? If that is the case, wouldn't I multiply by 4$\pi$ to go between per solid angle and the complete sphere? In which case equations 1 and 2 are still incompatible, as it would result in a $\pi$ squared?

Comment: I understand what you are asking now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from:

$$
I(\nu)=\frac{8 \pi \nu^{2} }{ c^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{e^{h \nu / k T}-1}\right)
$$

which the *flux* of photons per second per Hz per $4\pi$ solid angle per area.

That last one: per $4\pi$ steradian. That means "integrated over solid angle", as in:

$$\int_{\rm sphere}d\Omega = \int_{\cos{\theta}=-1}^1\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}d(\cos{\theta})d\phi=4\pi$$

There are 4$\pi$ steradians in a sphere, so to get to a directional intensity, you need to divide by $4\pi$.

If you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_intensity, you'll see there's often confusion between irradiance and intensity. Intensity is emitted power per steradian (and maybe Hz if it is spectral intensity), while irradiance (of confused with intensity) is received per unit area.

So the sphere emits over an area of $4\pi r^2$, while the disk receives energy over an area of $\pi r^2$...which is why you lose a  factor of 4.

As your source says:

*"The scalar irradiance
$E_o$
is related to the energy density by
$E_o=U\cdot c$. One way to see this is to think of the many photons making up the energy density. How many photons “hit” a small spherical detector per unit time, there to be recorded as scalar irradiance, equals how many photons there are times how fast they are moving, i.e.
$E_o=Uc$. Radiation in thermodynamic equilibrium is isotropic and unpolarized. For isotropic radiance,
$E_o=4E_d$, where
$E_d$
is the plane irradiance. Thus Eq. (2) can be converted to spectral plane irradiance by a factor of
$c∕4$"*

(Note that link uses energy per unit volume, $U$, which is related to power by a factor of $c$).

Comment: Always embarrassing when the answer is in the source you yourself link....